# iframe video is not working on iphone/ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, iframe, video

I just created a website on which we can download and watch movie for free using `PHP`. Now I am facing a problem with `embedded` video. I am using `<iframe>` code that is shown below to embed flash video.

```
echo '<iframe name="watch_online" id="watch_online" src="http://filehoot.com/embed-09uknzl64bw0-570x380.html" height="380" width="570" style="z-index:2147483647;" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
```

It works well on PC, but when I open it on iPhone, my flash video changes to `jwplayer` and it still cannot play the video. A message appears like this :

```
"the video could not be loaded either because the server or network failed or because the format is not support"
```

Guidance needed on this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no native flash players available for iOS, development purposes or otherwise, try uploading a HTML5 compatible video such as .mp4, .m4v, and .f4v file...

Detect iOS Device (javascript):

```
var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

if (uagent.search("iphone") > -1 ||
    uagent.search("ipod") > -1 ||
    uagent.search("ipad") > -1 ||
    uagent.search("appletv") > -1) {

    // handle code here for html5 video

}
```

Comment: no i mean is there'is any code that do something like:
if there is iphone or ipad detected it's load html5 video not flash video.

Comment: see update of detecting IOS device which don't support flash. Your video host filehoot.com doesn't support html5 mode, might be best to look at other providers that do this automatically